# Every user is logged in as the admin user whatever the user role/username

Tags: drupal-7

I have a serious login problem with my new (and first ever) Drupal 7 site.

I have two different users so far, which of one is the admin which was created while installing Drupal. If, I log in with the other user's username and password, still, the hovering admin menu will and the menu shows the username of the admin user. This happens, if I log in to both accounts from the same computer, but now I tested the non-admin account from a computer that have never been used to log in the particular site before, and the problem

I am using the current 7.34 core of Drupal 7. The login module is the built-in one of the core.

How is this possible and what can be done about it?

Comment: Anybody? I really need help with this...

Answer (score 0):

Remove cookies from your browser for this site

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your second user has not admin role.